# How can I clear a notification automatically after 30 seconds?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I am developing an application with iBeacons and I am trying to clean a notification of entering an region after 30 seconds of being spawming, something like the fireDate, any idea ?

Comment: You can use the `cancelLocalNotification` method of `UIApplication` but you can't really do it after 30 seconds because you can't schedule your app to run in the background like that. Possibly the best you can do is use a call to `didExitRegion` to clear the notification.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will help or I've understood your question correctly, but you can get the time from the event loop.You then just need to write a countUp function which increments second variable everytime its called. I suppose when seconds are 30 cancel notification.

```
public func start() { 
    // Create a timer object that calls the countUp method every second
    let timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: "countUp:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    // Get a reference to the current event loop
    let loop = NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop()
    // Attach the above timer to the event loop:
    // it will then actually start firing
    loop.addTimer(timer, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
}
```